# C# program does not recognize configuration file in python script

Tags: python, c#, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I have been working on an object detection project in image. I wrote the detection code in python with the Pycharm IDE. The program runs well in the IDE but I need to incorporate this into a Visual Studio project with C #. I did python script execution tests inside the C # program and everything went well for simple scripts using ProcessStartInfo (), however, when I run the detection project inside Visual Studio, the python script execution cannot find the project object class configuration file. I've tried to put the full path to the class configuration .json file in the python script, but another error occurs.

### Python project images

[image: Object class configuration file]

[image: Detection result in pycharm IDE]

### Python Script

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import CustomObjectDetection

detector = CustomObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath("Model/010--loss-0007.768.h5")
detector.setJsonPath("json\detection_config.json")
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image="Images/33.jpg", output_image_path="Images/New_33.jpg")
for detection in detections:
    print(detection["name"], " : ", detection["percentage_probability"], " : ", detection["box_points"])
```

### Visual Studio Image

[image: Visual Studio Image]

### C# Code

```
    public class ExecutePythonProcess
    {
        public static void ImageRecognition()
        {
            // 1) Create Process Info
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\Leonardo\anaconda3\envs\EpisDetection\python.exe";

            // 2) Provide script and arguments
            var script = @"D:\source\repos\EpisDetection\recognitionCustonImage.py";
            //var start = "2019-1-1";
            //var end = "2019-1-22";

            //psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{start}\" \"{end}\"";
            psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\"";

            // 3) Process configuration
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            // 4) Execute process and get output
            var errors = "";
            var results = "";

            using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // 5) Display output
            Console.WriteLine("ERRORS:");
            Console.WriteLine(errors);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Results:");
            Console.WriteLine(results);

        }
    }
```

### Error Message

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'json\detection_config.json'**

How do I make the script running in Visual Studio find the configuration file that is in my python script?

Comment: Can you try / in path?

Comment: I left the path like this:  detector.setJsonPath("/json/detection_config.json/"). But it still doesn't work